# Responsive issue after github upload

Tags: github, responsive-design, responsive

I'm facing some issues with my design.

1. After inspecting my phone viewport (414px) on my PC, my navbar is showing like [Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJWxH.png)

But when I browse through my real phone, my navbar is showing like [Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgMOJ.jpg). How do I solve this? I want my real phone to show up like image-1

2. After uploading my design to GitHub, my font (which I installed manually through CSS) is not working. Instead showing default font-family.
3. My website is showing a horizontal scroll on my phone. even though the scrolled space is totally blank.
4. Sometimes my browser (PC) is showing 60%–70% of the content horizontally while inspecting.

I've been trying for 5–6 hours but couldn't even find the issue! But I guess the fourth problem is a technical glitch. Sometimes refreshing or reopening the browser solves it. In addition, all my contents are under the container, and when the scroll appears, all my contents are vertically aligned perfectly.